# What is happening to my cat’s ear?

Tags: cats, health, skin-condition

It started on the inside and now it is all over her ear. The vet told us to put some cream on it. It got worse, so we have her in a cone and some antibiotics. Any have any idea? I’m so sad to see my kitty like visible on the attached photograph.

She is 3 years old and it’s been about a month. We have one more cat that seems fine. They are both indoor cats.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be many different things, from scabies to allergy or even a fungal infection.

You will have to take your cat to an other vet for a second opinion. The vet you are using now could have done a better job diagnosing and treating your cat.

It looks to me like this might be a fungal infection; if it is, then your other cat is at risk of getting it. However, I am in no way saying it will get it, only that there is a risk.

It does not look like it is an allergic reaction to me, but only a vet can tell this for sure; your vet might have given the right treatment, my guess is that the cream might have been an anti-fungal one.

Your vet will probably have to run some additional tests to find the cause for this, that ear does definitely not look good at all.